# relationship between normal and log-normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

In wikipedia it is stated that:

> If $X \sim \operatorname{Log-\mathcal{N}}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is distributed  log-normally, then $\ln(X) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is a normal random variable.

Is the converse true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, if $X$ is normal, then $\exp(X)$ is log-normal.

Answer (score 1):

More on X being normal while Y=exp(X) being log-normal:

[image]

Comment: I would clean up all references to $Ln$  to $\ln$.